# Delete row from table conditional on a related table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: Store and Company. I want to be able to delete a store based on the information of its company.
Initially I tried:

```
DELETE FROM Store WHERE (SELECT * FROM Company WHERE companyValueA > 5).company_id = store.company_id AND store.wf = 0;
```

But this isnt working. I was thinking about doing a join of the two and deleting from the join like this:

```
DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM Store LEFT JOIN Company ON Store.company_id = Company.company_id) WHERE companyValueA > 5 AND wf = 0;
```

but that isnt working either. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Please post the structures of `Store, Company` from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Store; SHOW CREATE TABLE Company;` Your first attempt seems to imply that there are multiple company tables, as though stores have their own..

Comment: Where does `establishment` come from?

Comment: store used to be establishment, accidentally typed it instead of store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess... obviously, make a backup before attempting this!!!

```
DELETE s 
  FROM store s
  JOIN company c
    ON c.company_id = s.company_id 
 WHERE c.companyValueA > 5
   AND s.wf = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MYSQL's DELETE with JOIN syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) (i haven't used it) or just collect all the store id's to be deleted with subquery if you need a more compatible statement:

```
DELETE
  FROM store
 WHERE store_id IN (
                     SELECT S.store_id
                       FROM store S, company C
                      WHERE C.company_id = S.company_id
                        AND C.companyValueA > 5
                        AND S.wf = 0
                     )
```